# How do I replace a string with multiple matches from an arraylist?

Tags: java

Say I have the a string like `String x "This is an example string!";`

I'm trying to find certain all the words like `[This, an, string]`from an array and replace all of them with * in `x` if the match(es) are found.

So far I've tried along with similar variations:

```
List<String> index = new ArrayList();
 index.add("This");
 index.add("an");
 index.add("example");
 String words = index.toString().replaceFirst("\\[", "").replaceFirst("\\]", "");       
 Boolean result = x.contains(words);
 if (result == true){
 String newMessage = x.replaceAll("[words.split(\\W+)]", "*");
 }
```

This sort of works but requires that the has to string contain `This, an, string` in the exact order as it appears withing the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each word in your `List`. Replace that in `x` with a `*`, assigning the result back to `x`. Something like,

```
List<String> index = Arrays.asList("This", "an", "example");
String x = "This is an example string!";
for (String str : index) {
  x = x.replace(str, "*");
}
System.out.println(x);
```

Output is

```
* is * * string!
```

Comment: What would be the best way to change Array.asList = ...  to pull from a YAML file, ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
List<String> index = // ...
String message = "This is an example string!";
for (String word : index) {
    message = message.replace(word, "*");
}
```

Comment: This method worked for replacing the first word, This, but it left the rest untouched, " * is an example string! ". Thanks for sharing this though.